Is "are we forgetting something?" wrong?
I asked this question on Quora

I am helping my daughter to put all her books into her backpack before
she goes to school. I want her to confirm if these are all the books
she needs.
Is it natural to say "Are we forgetting something?" in this situation?

One (I guess he is a native English speaker by looking at his name) said:

No, it would be better to say “Have you forgotten anything?” Or “Is
that everything.?”
When we use ‘forget’, it’s nearly always in the past tense because you
forgot something, generally speaking at the time of forgetting you
don’t realize you’re doing it. You could of course use the imperative
“Don’t forget anything!”

However, in Oxford dictionary, we have this example

Aren't you forgetting something? (= I think you have forgotten to do
something)

So, I guess "forget" can be used in continuous tenses.
In the packing-the-backpack situation above,
Is "are we forgetting something?" wrong?
Alternatively, "is that everything?" or "are those everything?" is short and concise, but I don't see many as a standalone sentence  on Google Books.

Are we forgetting anything? would express to your daughter that the two of you are cooperating in staying organized, whereas something
could imply that you know something is indeed being overlooked and want her to tell you what it is.  And if you use "Aren't" instead of "Are" that is certainly the meaning.

There's nothing remotely wrong with OP's Are we forgetting something? - but idiomatically, we're far more likely to use the negated version as found in the Oxford dictionary. Here's the usage chart of published written instances over the past half-century...


Note that negated continuous Aren't we forgetting something? is usually a rhetorical question. It carries the strong implication that the speaker knows something obvious has been ignored, and is expecting the addressee to explicitly recall and acknowledge the omission.
Note that in most contexts, using we (instead of Aren't you forgetting something?) is inherently contemptuous. This is acceptable when speaking as a parent to a child, but should usually be avoided in adult conversation unless it's facetiously alluding to the parent/child relationship.
For a genuine inquiry (speaker wants all parties to consider carefully whether anything has been forgotten), the usual form is Present Perfect Have we forgotten anything? (Is there anything that we have forgotten?). You should avoid using something in the genuine question, lest it be mistaken for the contemptuous rhetorical question.

Why is "Aren't we forgetting something?" inherently contemptuous? I thought "Aren't we forgetting something?" does not target "you". "Aren't you forgetting something?" targets "you" and thus more contemptuous.

For the same reason How are we feeling today? when asked by the hospital doctor doing his morning rounds is inherently contemptuous. Maybe the gratuitous switch from second person singular to first person plural doesn't occur, or has no significance in your language. But for Anglophones it's only normally used by an adult speaking to a child, so it should be avoided in other situations. (I hope we're quite clear on that point now! :)

So Which one is more polite? "you forgot the book" and "we forgot the book". For the former, I blamed only my daughter for forgetting the book, but for the latter, both took responsible for it.

"you forgot the book" and "we forgot the book" are just two different statements with different meanings - possibly affected by the matter of who was responsible for making sure something wasn't forgotten. It's got nothing to do with why How are we feeling today? when addressed to an adult of equal / higher social status is likely to be perceived as presumptuous / offensive.

"Are we forgetting something?" might be used, asking for confirmation, if the idea of forgetting something had already been raised.
On the other hand, "Are we forgetting anything?" might be asked without a previous suggestion of forgetting, just to make sure.
"Is that everything?" is idiomatic.
In the case of a final check before departure, I think "are we forgetting" is more natural than "have we forgotten".
The latter would be used if they had already departed, because after departure, it's a fact of the past, and the damage has been done.

I don't think Are we forgetting anything? is at all common. Negated Aren't we forgetting something? is often a kind of rhetorical question carrying the strong implication that the speaker knows something obvious has been ignored, and is expecting the addressee to explicitly recall and acknowledge the omission. For a genuine inquiry, the usual form is Have we forgotten anything? (Is there anything we have forgotten?).
